# Who is adding Facebook meta tags

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I added the following to the HTML of my front page (right from the top of the page):

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
<meta name="description" content="Blah-Blah-Blah This is my web site">
<meta name="keywords" content="why,does,facebook,suck,so,much">
<meta name="distribution" content="Global">
<meta name="revisit-after" content="30 days">
<meta name="rating" content="General">
<meta name="robots" content="follow,index">
<meta name="author" content="www.me-at-my-wonderful-site.com">
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title" />
<meta property="og:type" content="company" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.my-company-url.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.my-company-url.com/images/facebook_pic.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="My Company Name" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Blah-Blah-Blah" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789012345"/>
<meta property="og:latitude" content="56.340609"/>
<meta property="og:longitude" content="-152.435136"/>
<meta property="og:street-address" content="123 1st St."/>
<meta property="og:locality" content="Seattle"/>
<meta property="og:region" content="WA"/>
<meta property="og:postal-code" content="98765"/>
<meta property="og:country-name" content="USA"/>
<meta property="og:phone_number" content="360-123-4567"/>
<title>Title for my web page - Home Page</title>
<link href="icon.ico" rel="SHORTCUT ICON">
<link href="styles.css" type=text/css rel=stylesheet>
<!-- Regular HTML follows -->
```

Let's say the following can be accessed by logging in to http://www.my-company-url.com and I can see the HTML above in a web browser (view source). But when I load the same URL into http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug I get the following:

```
Errors That Must Be Fixed
Object Invalid Value:   Object at URL 'http://www.my-company-url.com' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '123456789012345' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.
Missing Required Property:  The og:url property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property:  The og:type property is required, but not present.
Missing Required Property:  The og:title property is required, but not present.
```

and then this

```
Warnings That Should Be Fixed
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:latitude.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:longitude.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:street-address.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:locality.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:region.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:postal-code.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:country-name.
Extraneous Property:    Objects of this type do not allow properties named og:phone_number.
```

Now WTF is this? Didn't I specify all those parameters above in my HTML??? And as you can see I made it "company" and not the "website"...

PS. 123456789012345 is not my real facebook ID, but it has the same number of digits as my actual ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > Object Invalid Value:   Object at URL 'http://www.my-company-url.com' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '123456789012345' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.
>
> 123456789012345 is not my real facebook ID, but it has the same number of digits as my actual ID.

The `fb:app_id` tag is supposed to be the ID number of a Facebook application, not your personal Facebook profile's ID. If you want to manage a page through your Facebook profile, you should be using `fb:admins`, not `fb:app_id`. I suspect that this error is having some sort of cascading effect, preventing Facebook's parser from dealing with the rest of your OpenGraph tags.

For more details, see the *Page Administration* section of [Facebook's OpenGraph documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/).

Comment: Thanks, Martey. This is actually a business page and not a personal profile. It sounds simple, but where would I get the value for fb:admins?

Comment: `fb:admins` uses the Facebook User IDs of the people who should administrate the page. To get your user ID, go to https://graph.facebook.com/USERNAME, where USERNAME is your Facebook username.

Comment: Oh, boy. This one isn't easy. The question I have, why is this facebook still around? I was able to get rid of errors after adding Insights to my page (whatever that is).

Comment: But, OK, seriously, after fixing errors I now get a bunch of warnings about og:latitude and og:longitude and for some reason the og:type: becomes "website" when it clearly states "company" in my mark-up. Any idea why?

Comment: As Daniel Tsyganok noted in his answer, it would be easier to help you if you provided a link to the page in question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you didn't specify the Open Graph name space.

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#">
```

More information on the API here
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

Comment: On that url there is this: `xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml"` instead of the suggested `xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#"`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on a wordpress based site I run, I was able to fix it by adding the open graph meta tags again at the body and as weird as it sounds, it actually worked.

I might be of a greater help if you post the site in discussion.

Comment: That is clearly against all HTML guidelines, whatever facebook may think about it...